# CSS style on Radio and checked button is not working in RCP app e4

Tags: css, button, radio-button, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am aware that changing the background of buttons in RCP apps in e4 does not work.

From the Vogella tutorial [Eclipse 4 CSS Styling](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html).

*"For example, the SWT implementation for Windows does not allow to set the background color of the Button and the ScrollBar widget."*

I should still be able to change the color of the text written for radio and checked buttons. But it doesn't seem to be applied. The wizard remains with black text despite I set it to light grey in my CSS file using the Pseudo Classes *Button:checked, :active, or :selected*

Same with Group titles

Comment: Button:checked works for me on macOS with checked buttons.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I ma on Windows 10 and the code in my CSS stylesheet looks as such `Button:checked {
  color: #F9F9F9;
}`

Comment: Are you starting off with the button unchecked and expecting the styling to change when you check the button?

Comment: Yes the button was unchecked. Any styling with Pseudo classes is fine. I just want to know it is possible. So i tried :active and :selected. Nothing changed it.

Comment: As far as I can see :active only works on Shells and :selected on tab folders. So I don't think the pseudo classes will work for you as explained in my answer. I would use a selection listener and use IStylingEngine to change the controls CSS class (added to answer).

Answer (score 0):

Testing here it appears that this will work only if the button is already checked when the dialog appears.

Changing the check state of the button doesn't change the styling.

This is because the code in the Button CSS handler `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.dom.ButtonElement` does not currently support dynamically changing the styling to match the check state.

There is a property you can set to turn on dynamic styling:

```
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.dynamic", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
```

**BUT** Eclipse bug [362532](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362532) says that this can cause problems.

So this basically isn't going to work.

An alternative is to use `IStylingEngine` and change the id or class of the buttons in a selection listener.